# How to check a checkbox of form 1 from another form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have two forms, form 1 and form 2 (windows application). How can i access and check a checkbox in form 1 from form 2. Initially i tried calling the form name and then the control like `form1.chkCanada.checked = true`, it did not work. And then i added a property in form 1

```
Public Property abc As Boolean
    Get
        Return chkCanadianStmtInd.Checked
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        chkCanadianStmtInd.Checked = value
    End Set
End Property
```

and then in form 2

```
Dim frm As New frm1
frm.abc = True  'Checked
```

And it still doesnt work. Am i missing anything here?

Comment: does form 1 create an instance of form 2 or does form 2 create an instance of form 1?

Comment: I dont think i understood am sorry.

Comment: ok, when you do: `Dim frm As New frm1` you are creating an instance of the frm1 class. Since that is contained on form 2, form 2 becomes the owner or parent of the object `frm`. before you do `Dim frm As New frm1` on form 2 has the user already seen form 1?

Comment: In form 1 i have a button, when i click on it, it opens form 2. Where in there is a dorpbox, if canada is selected in the drop box, in ok button click event, the checkbox called chkCanadianStmtInd should get checked.

Comment: Yes the user has already seen the form 1.

Comment: so your problem is you are not referencing the instance of form1 that the user has already seen, you are referencing a new version of form 1 that you are creating in form2. you need to raise an even from form2 and handle it on form1 in order to check the box on form1 from form2

Comment: Yes i understood that now, thanks for the explanation its pretty clear. Can u give me any example how can i achieve this?

Comment: Well the above would not compile.

Comment: The code is a little jumbled.  Public Property abc As Boolean        Get
        Return chkCanadianStmtInd.Checked
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        chkCanadianStmtInd.Checked = value
    End Set
End Property

Comment: Also it should be frm.abc =  true in form2

Answer (score 0):

Consolidating comments here:

In order to access controls on a form that shows another form to the user you have two options, if no interaction is needed with the first form while the second form is active you can use `showdialog` and do all of your logic after the second form has closed, if you ned to maintain the ability to interact with the first form while the second is still open then you need to use custom events.

Showdialog:

The simpler of the two options is to switch your `form.show()` function calls to `form.showdialog()`. This effectively tells the first form that it should stop processing at the `form.showdialog()` line and wait for the child form to close before proceeding. Once the second form is closed the first form will pick up where it left off and that would be where any processing that relies on the values of the second form would take place.

Custom Events:

If you want to allow the user to interact with both the first and second forms at the same time then you will need to use custom events. In order to do this you will need three things. The custom event, a raiseevent call and an event handler.

So in your Form2 class you will need to declare the custom event. In this case since you are trying to check(or uncheck I assume) a box your custom event declaration will look like:

```
public event ChangeCheckedValue(byref state as boolean)
```

Now on your button click event you will need to raise the event to the handler on Form1:

```
RaiseEvent ChangeCheckedValue(booleanValue)
```

Now that those statements are in place you will need to changed your form2 object that is being shown by Form1. What I normally do is make Form2 a form wide variable on Form1 and declare it like:

```
private withevents frm as Form2
```

Once you have the frm variable in your Form1 class you can add a handler for the `ChangeCheckedValue` event:

```
protected sub HandleCheckChanged(byref bln as boolean) handles frm.ChangeCheckedValue
    'Set the checked state of your checkbox.
End sub
```

Once you have all that set up you should see what you expect.

Comment: That was so clean and clear, let me try that real quick. Thank you so very much Mike :)

Comment: What will be the booleanvalue?

Comment: I added public event ChangeCheckedValue(byref state as boolean) in form 2 and in form 2 button click i have raised the event RaiseEvent ChangeCheckedValue(booleanValue).

Comment: And then i added private withevents frm as Form2 & Protected Sub HandleCheckChanged(ByRef bln As Boolean) Handles frmSiteSettlement.ChangeCheckedValue
        'Set the checked state of your checkbox.
        chkCanadianStmtInd.Checked = True
    End Sub in form 1. Its still not updating it. Am doing something wrong here?

Comment: make sure you are declaring `frmSiteSettlement` with events and show that form to the user. when you raise the event the booleanValue argumnt will be either true or false depending on what you want to set the checkbox checked state to. I'm not sure if you have a value on Form2 that controls that or how thats decided so booleanValue was my place holder, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have declared frmSiteSettlement with events. And here is the code snippet am using in the button click where we are raising the event

Comment: If cboSiteID.SelectedItem.Value = SiteID.Canada Then
                bCanadianSite = True
                RaiseEvent ChangeCheckedValue(bCanadianSite) Also it is not hitting the break point in the event handler. Not sure what mistake am doing :(

Comment: its hard to tell. there is a disconnect somewhere between your listener and your raiseevent. Without seeing the code its hard to tell.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the help, I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Is there any reason form2 can't just be shown as a dialog, then you read the value of the appropriate controls when the form is closed with the OK button?

Comment: This application is built n I was just told to fix this issue, I dont think they would like to change the way it works right now, thats the biggest problem.

Comment: If you don't need to interact with Form1 at all while Form2 is shown you can switch the `form2.show()` call to `form2.showdialog()` and then put your checked changed logic directly after the `showdialog` function call. This would eliminate the need for the custom events but would also lock the user out of form1 while form2 was visible.

Comment: Thats exactly what i have been researching. Somehow showdialog doesnt show the form 2. I tried a little rnd using the showdialog adding two forms, they worked perfectly fine, but not in this case.

Comment: Mike_OBrien I found the issue, it was at the very beginning we are creating an instance for the form1 because of which it was not working, once i commented those lines, it worked. Now i can directly call the form 1 check box in form 2 and update it. Thank you so much for ur time and support!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can pass a handle of form1 to form2 constructor

Form1:

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim _form2 As New Form2(Me)

    _form2.Show()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Form2:

```
Public Class Form2

  Public Sub New(ByVal _form1 As Form1)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    _form1.CheckBox1.Checked = True

  End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: I tried the same, but the forms are not talking to each other, this is also not working.